# iOS local notification - screen unlock

Tags: ios, notifications, unlock

From my app I need to play a sound while generating a local notification (something like what happens when receiving a whatsapp call for example).

When the phone is locked, the local notification appears on the lock screen and the sound is played fine. During this, if the phone is unlocked by swiping on the notification icon, the app opens and things go on nice and smooth.

However, while the notification is on, if the phone is unlocked by **not** swiping on the app icon, but in the normal way (by swiping on the lower portion of the screen) the notification is lost. I do not see the notification back after the screen is unlocked, nor does the sound play any longer.

Can I have some clues to make the notification appear back after screen unlock and keep the sound playing?

Comment: The notification moves to the notification centre once the phone is unlocked. If you want to generate continuous audio then you need to use an audio background mode

Comment: That is true, but if you see like they are doing for whatsapp, the notification comes back after the phone is unlocked. I want to do something similar.

Comment: VoIP apps are different. Are you writing a voip app?

Comment: yes, you are correct